# How get map extents for drawn polygon when final click is done?

Tags: openlayers-2, geoext, ext-js

I am using OpenLayers JS to draw a polygon and now I want map extents of the drawn polygon one final click (i.e. user finish drawing polygon or double click is done). For drawing the polygon I am using following code:

```
action = Ext.create('GeoExt.Action', {
        text: "Draw Poly",
        icon: 'Images/poly.png',
        control: new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(
            vector, OpenLayers.Handler.Polygon
        ),
        map: map,
        // button options
        toggleGroup: "draw",
        allowDepress: false,
        tooltip: "Draw Polygon",
        // check item options
        group: "draw"
    });
```

This code is written using OpenLayers JS, Ext JS and GeoExt JS.

Can anyone please tell me how to get map extents for the drawn polygon?

Comment: Do you want the extent, after the user has drawn the polygon? have you looked at the Polygon.getBounds() function?

Comment: yes i want the polygon extends after user finish drawing. i have to do once user finish drawing in this case Polygon.getBounds() will help? how please guide me or give sample reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to listen to the featureadded event of the vector layer, and then get the geometry there.

Have a look at the following JavaScript code:

```
var map;
function init(){
    map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');

    var wmsLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "OpenLayers WMS",
        "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0?", {layers: 'basic'});

    var polygonLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Polygon Layer");

    map.addLayers([wmsLayer,polygonLayer]);
    map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition());

   var  polygon= new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(polygonLayer,OpenLayers.Handler.Polygon);

    map.addControl(polygon);


    map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(0, 0), 3);

    //activate the control
    polygon.activate();

    //register the event listner
    polygonLayer.events.register('featureadded',polygonLayer, onAdded);
}

function onAdded(ev){
    var polygon=ev.feature.geometry;
    var bounds=polygon.getBounds();
    //now do whatever you want with the bounds
    //I'm just logging it to the console                
    console.log(bounds);
}
```

You can also see this working example: http://jsfiddle.net/devdatta/sFaag/

Comment: Thanks for this, but how i will use using openlayer js , extjs and geoext js. please see my code for that.

Comment: You have a vector layer called 'vector', right? Then just call vector.events.register('featureadded',vector, onAdded); and add the required onAdded function somewhere in your js file.

Comment: sorry for that. please see if accepted is checked now